# track a guest user's actions on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, tracking

Is it possible in iPhone if we can track users actions? Like which applications he has opened, sent messages or calls etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: no

Apps cannot access the usage information of different apps.

There is a (work arround) solution by implementing a Proxy-App, which provides a proxy server and registers this proxy server in the preferences. All network data would pass that proxy and your Proxy-App could send usage statistics to your server.

However, you can only track network traffic, not other usage statistics. Moreover, this App would never pass the App Review process...